# rectangle not drawing where I want and how to work with a spritebatch.begin() with a transform matrix

Tags: c#, matrix, xna, transform

basically I need to make a game in xna with a 6-man team for college, and we are stuck at one problem.
We have buttons, which are basically textures with a rectangle to see whether the mouse is inside the rectangle when clicked. We have a method for this, which returns true when the mouse is inside the rectangle when clicked. The rectangles x and y coords are the same as the texture, and it has the textures width and height.

Now recently we have started with implementing fullscreen and scaling, using a transform matrix in the spritebatch.begin().
Here is the code going into calculating that transformation:

```
public static void Update(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime gT)
{
    if (enToFollow != null)
        v2CameraPosition = enToFollow.PropLocalPosition;

    if (Data.PropApplyGraphics)
        ApplyGraphics();

    transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-v2CameraPosition.X, -v2CameraPosition.Y, 0.0f) *spriteScale;
    v2SpriteScale = new Vector2(scale.X, scale.Y);
}

/// <summary>
/// Clears the camera target. Causes the camera to stand still.
/// </summary>
public static void SetNull()
{ enToFollow = null; }

/// <summary>
/// Sets the camera target to follow a certain object. It will instantly jump to the target!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="enToFollow">Target to follow.</param>
public static void SetTarget(Entity enToFollowNew)
{ enToFollow = enToFollowNew; }

public static void ApplyGraphics()
{
    scalex = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width / (float)screen.X;
    scaley = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height / (float)screen.Y;
    finalscale = 1f;

    if (!Data.PropIsFullscreen)
    {
        if (scalex < 1f || scaley < 1f)
            finalscale = Math.Min(scalex, scaley);
    }
    else
    {
        finalscale = scalex;
        if (Math.Abs(1 - scaley) < Math.Abs(1 - scalex))
            finalscale = scaley;
    }

    scale = new Vector2((float)Data.GetSetScreenDimensions.X / screen.X, (float)Data.GetSetScreenDimensions.Y / screen.Y);
    spriteScale = Matrix.CreateScale(scale.X, scale.Y, 1);
    Data.PropApplyGraphics = false;
}
```

The matrix created in the update, can be retrieved by a property in this same class, which returns that matrix and is used in the spritebatch.begin() like this:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, null, null, null, null, Camera.PropTransform);
```

when I go fullscreen with a 1080p resolution set in graphicsdevice.preferredbackbufferwidth en height, the positions where the buttons are drawn, are multiplied by the spritescale which is being calculated within the above applygraphics() method. yet, the rectangles aren't affected by this multiplication. anyway, when I try to make that happen, with the vector2 spritescale which is calculated in the update, it doesn't return the rectangle correctly.

Let me elaborate, the code for the multiplication of the created vector2 with the starting coordinates of the rectangle is like this, in the hope of letting the rectangle match the sprite again:

```
public Rectangle PropRectangle
{ 
    get { return new Rectangle((int)this.PropRealPosition.X * (int)Camera.PropSpriteScale.X, (int)this.PropRealPosition.Y * (int)Camera.PropSpriteScale.Y, inTextureWidth, inTextureHeight); } 
}
```

yet, when I have this rectangle written to console, it still returns a rectangle like the above multiplication never happened, even though the Camera.PropSpriteScale.X en .Y have values of about 1.42 ish (1920 / 1344 and 1080 / 756). Why does this happen like that ?

Another question is, how do I deal with this scaling issue properly, while keeping my buttons working ?